# How to connect a Machine(Computer) with Wifi server by passing Credentials

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I have to develop a Wifi Server Billing application for internet data usage.Now here is my flow of work..

```
1.Any System in the Wifi range will require Username and Password to get connected with the Wifi Server.
2.The moment any system gets connected into the Wifi Server after passing correct username and password My application should know the IP address of the system along with Connection time.
3.Now from there whatever data is used by that System (Ip address) should get recorded in my system.
```

This is all in the flow that i have thought to develop as basic wifi billing application.

So how can i proceed to get this application developed.I am bit aware of TCP/Ip and Socket Programming in c#.

Any suggestion or help is highly appreciated..

Thanks..

Comment: Well, i recommend you stay by taking a guess at how to implement each step, then try then, then pose questions asking what went wrong in the areas where you get stuck. Just asking 'how do i stay implementing this entire project' isn't a suitable question for this forum, i think.

Answer (score 2):

There's way too much to talk about this to be suitable here but essentially you need to ensure that no host is allowed to connect and have traffic is routed for it based on MAC address until it's been granted access by your billing system. For such hosts you only allow them to "talk to" a certain IP/port which serves the website for your billing system.

In order to accomplish this you will need a way to interface directly with the WIFI access point, and the router (which might be the same device or different devices).

There are a few such systems available out there already and even if you're prepared to follow the white rabbit you should still familiarize yourself with what's out there. Try to learn how and why these systems work and their limitations. Then you can attempt to roll your own, or perhaps integrate with or extend an already existing one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable suggestion.It will be best if you can point me to a place from where i can start ..Thanks